# Open a project in IntelliJ from folder

Tags: intellij-idea

How may I open a project in IntelliJ IDE by navigating to it in windows explorer ?
Here is my folder where I want to open the project in IntellIj

[image]

I want to avoid using the "open project" in the IntelliJ interface as this :

[image]

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want to do a right-click in the folder then have an option "open with IntelliJ" proposed?

Comment: yes for example, or double click on something

Comment: I think you could take a look at [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors) to manage right-click menu options. I don't know if it possible to launch intellij with a folder to open in parameters.

Comment: last versions of intellif offer during installation the option to  add a context menu "open as project".

You can also use command line.

    cd your/directory  

   then type the command   "idea.exe .". 
This will open the current directory as intellij project

Answer (score 35):

**Windows 8.1**

1. Right click on Start Icon (bottom left) and click on Run.
2. Run '**regedit**' (system program)
3. Click 'Yes' to allow program to make changes to computer.
4. In the left panel, under 'Computer' select '**HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT**'
5. Scroll down to '**Directory**' (Quite far down the list)
6. Right click on '**shell**' and select '**New > Key**'
7. Type in name of action (can be anything)
8. Right Click on your new Key and add another new Key
9. Name new Key '**command**' (mandantory)
10. Click on command and right click on '**(Default)**', then click Modify...
11. Set Value Data to your Intellij IDEA program location plus '**%1**'
    (I set mine to "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.4\bin\idea64.exe %1").
    Also, on **Windows 10**, set Value Data to your Intellij IDEA program location plus "**%1**" (I set mine to "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.1\bin\idea64.exe" "%1").
12. Click on the Key you made in step 6 and set '(Default)' value to the text you want to see
13. Go to your folder and Enjoy!

Also, if you want an icon, do this:

1. Go to the Key you made in step 6
2. Right Click and choose '**New > String Value**'
3. Name it '**Icon**' (mandantory)
4. Right Click > Modify...
5. Set Data Value to Intellij IDEA exe file

Here is a GIF with the steps:
[Giphy.com](https://giphy.com/gifs/java-windows-81-intellij-idea-tsX4ORSWHdZpZkS1O3)

I hope you found this helpful! Good Luck!

Answer (score 13):

Top answser doesn't work on Windows 11 (and maybe 10). Here are the correct steps.

### STEP 1: Create your context menu option

1. Open your Registry Editor by pressing WIN + R, then typing `regedit`.
2. Go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` **⚠️ Do not forget the Background folder, which is missing from other Stackoverflow answers.**
3. Right click on the `shell` folder, then `New`, then `Key`.
4. Name the folder as you like, for example `IntelliJ`.

### STEP 2: Name your context menu option

1. Click on the folder corresponding to your context menu option, `IntelliJ` for me.
2. Right click on `(Default)`, then `Modify...`.
3. In the `value data` field, name your context menu option, for example `Open as project`.

### STEP 3: Set the action when the context menu option is clicked

1. Right click on the folder corresponding to your context menu option, `IntelliJ` for me.
2. Click on `New`, then `Key`.
3. Type `command`.
4. Click on the command folder you have created.
5. Right click on `(Default)`, then `Modify...`.
6. Type `"PATH TO idea64.exe" "%V"`, for me it's `"C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5284.40\bin\idea64.exe" "%V"`

Complete this third step allow you to see your context menu in the right click folder. Clicking on it will open IntelliJ in the current folder.

### STEP 4: Set an icon to the context menu option

1. Right click on the folder corresponding to your context menu option, `IntelliJ` for me.
2. Click on `New`, then `String value`.
3. Name it `Icon`.
4. Right click on `Icon`, then `Modify...`.
5. Type the path to your idea64.exe, for me it's `C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\212.5284.40\bin\idea64.exe`.

Comment: You can get your the path to your ide from its shortcut by right-clicking on the app icon, click properties, under shortcut tab, you'll find the path in `target` field.

Comment: is possible go to exe trought .lnk (file shortcut)?

Answer (score 7):

To add to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780073
Make sure that Step 11 looks something like : "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1\bin\idea64.exe" "%1"

Note the separate "%1". Otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't allow you to open a project from a folder, you can install the [Jetbrains toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/) to manage your projects and product versions.

You can easily open projects from it while avoiding the "open project" interface of intellij. You can also assign a shortcut to it for even faster use.

This screenshot demontrates how you can search for a project. Simply navigate to it using the arrow keys and pressing enter opens the project for you.
[image: screenshot of jetbrains toolbox]

Answer (score 3):

To this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780073/7975816
The value in step 11 didn't work for me but `"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe" " %V"` did the job.
I have the value inspired from VSCode.
I posted this in case someone else is looking for Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

1.Locate the IntelliJ IDEA executable file (idea64.exe) on your system. By default, it can be found in the "bin" folder of your IntelliJ IDEA installation directory.

2. Right-click on the Windows Start button and select "Run" (or use the Windows Key + R shortcut).
3. In the Run dialog box, type "regedit" and press Enter to open the Registry Editor.
4. In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following path: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
5. Right-click on the "shell" key and select "New" -> "Key". Name the new key "Open with IntelliJ IDEA" (or any other name you prefer).
6. Right-click on the new key and select "New" -> "Key". Name the new key "command".
7. In the right-hand pane, double-click on the "(Default)" value and enter the following path: "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\bin\idea64.exe" "%V"

Note: Replace the path with the actual path to the idea64.exe file on your system, and make sure to include the quotes around the path and the "%V" parameter.

8. Click "OK" to save the changes.
9. Close the Registry Editor.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know, so far, is uninstalling and reinstalling the program.

This way during the installation windows faze, there will be a box you can tick so that the "Open folder as IDEA Project" is added automatically.

Just make sure when uninstalling to NOT choose to "delete" all the settings data etc.

[image]